# XSLT : Copy Input xml including child nodes to an attribute in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

could you please help me in acheving below expected output using xslt.

> Input

```
<Order OrderNotificationID="123456" OrderNo="40003773" >       
<OrderLines>
<OrderLine Action="CANCEL" EAN="" LineNo="1"> </OrderLine>
        <OrderLine Action="CANCEL" EAN="" LineNo="4"> </OrderLine>
    </OrderLines> 
</Order>
```

> Expected Ouput

```
<NewXML InputXML= "<Order OrderNotificationID="123456" OrderNo="40003773"><OrderLines>
<OrderLine Action="CANCEL" EAN="" LineNo="1"/>
<OrderLine Action="CANCEL" EAN="" LineNo="4"/>
</OrderLines></Order>" />
```

Comment: This expected output is not well-formed, you can't put markup in XML attributes. XSLT won't help you produce malformed XML. Some engines still make it possible through technicalities but they're not helpful trying to get this result.

Comment: I'm happy even if i get a raw xml with nodes and attributes

Comment: *"I'm happy even if i get a raw xml with nodes and attributes "* So why not just use `xsl:copy-of`?

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to put the serialization of the input XML into an attribute value then you need to write code or use a libary that serializes XML to a string, the sample

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:import href="http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/xml-to-string.xsl"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:variable name="serialized-xml">
          <xsl:apply-templates mode="xml-to-string"/>
      </xsl:variable>
      <NewXML InputXml="{$serialized-xml}"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

uses the library from http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/. But you need to understand that well-formed XML output means that characters like `<` and `"` will be escaped in the attribute value so the result looks like

```
<NewXML InputXml="&lt;Order OrderNotificationID=&quot;123456&quot; OrderNo=&quot;40003773&quot;&gt;       &#xA;&lt;OrderLines&gt;&#xA;&lt;OrderLine Action=&quot;CANCEL&quot; EAN=&quot;&quot; LineNo=&quot;1&quot;&gt; &lt;/OrderLine&gt;&#xA;        &lt;OrderLine Action=&quot;CANCEL&quot; EAN=&quot;&quot; LineNo=&quot;4&quot;&gt; &lt;/OrderLine&gt;&#xA;    &lt;/OrderLines&gt; &#xA;&lt;/Order&gt;" />
```